# SQL: delete one (or all) record among 2 or more records with older date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to achieve something like this, which is NOT possible at the moment in SQL Server 2000.

```
DELETE 
    TOP 1 
FROM 
    attendance 
WHERE 
    student_id = '201601292' 
ORDER BY 
    attend_date ASC
```

Unintentionally, somehow duplicate records have been entered in the table and i want to delete all duplicates but the latest (or the oldest) one.

Note that the table has **no primary key**. As it is SQL Server version 2000, `'WITH'` keyword is not available. Also, `'attend_date'` column is a `datetime` column.

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two rows with the same latest date? Keep both, or just one of them (which one?)?

Comment: At least the time portion of the 'datetime' column will be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, should work with any dbms:

```
DELETE FROM attendance WHERE student_id = '201601292'
AND attend_date < (select max(attend_date)
                   from attendance WHERE student_id = '201601292')
```

Or, more general, for all students:

```
DELETE FROM attendance a1
WHERE attend_date < (select max(attend_date)
                   from attendance WHERE student_id = a1.student_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

### EDIT removed the alias for the target table (syntax error)

```
DELETE FROM attendance 
WHERE attendance.attendance_date NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX(x.attendance_date) FROM attendance AS x WHERE x.student_id=attendance.student_id
);
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. DO you know Why?

Comment: Make it as "DELETE a FROM attendance"

Comment: @user1451111 Sorry, the target table cannot have an alias... edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to use below code:

```
DECLARE @attendance TABLE (student_id VARCHAR(20), attend_date  date);
INSERT INTO @attendance (student_id, attend_date ) VALUES
('201601292','Feb 3 2017'),
('201601292','Feb 4 2017'),
('201601292','Mar 1 2017'),
('201601293','Feb 3 2017'),
('201601293','Feb 4 2017'),
('201601293','Mar 1 2017')


DELETE A FROM @attendance A
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT student_id,MAX(attend_date) AS attend_date  FROM @attendance 
    GROUP BY student_id
    ) B 
ON A.student_id <> B.student_id AND A.attend_date <> B.attend_date

SELECT * FROM @attendance
```

OUTPUT

```
student_id  attend_date
201601292   2017-03-01
201601293   2017-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` to include the unmatched rows for deletion, something like this :

```
DELETE 
FROM  
    attendance a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        student_id, MAX(attend_date) 
    FROM 
        attendance
    GROUP BY 
        student_id
    ) b
ON 
    a.student_id <> b.student
AND 
    a.attend_date <> b.attend_date
```

You can refer to this [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b58a0/4) to try it out.